# iTunes transaction history API for developers

Tags: iphone, itunes

I am attempting to integrate iPhone sales data into our statistics software.

I need to download a list of all iPhone purchases, including rebill/cancel data for **subscriptions** that occurred under our iTunes developer account.

Is there any Transaction History API for iTunes that will give me access to this information?

I know I can manually check each subscription to see if it's still active after it expires, but that isn't really reliable for financial reporting and it doesn't provide any details about chargebacks or returns.

Ideally I'd like the equivalent of the android market's "Notification History API" - https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Notification_History_API

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I haven't found anything solid from Apple which is why a large majority of developers use services such as [AppAnnie](http://appannie.com) or [AppFigures](http://appfigures.com) for reporting. You can manually scan the report but I have yet to see an API that handles this. AppFigures does have an [API](http://docs.appfigures.com)

[Reporting](http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf)